# restart program every x minutes?

Tags: linux, debian

I have a mutithreaded Java program which uses a opensource library and this library has some bugs which cause deadlock I've reported the bug but it will take time for it to get fixed, I would need to continue using this program and as long as it restarts every 2-3 hours it will do the job for me. Is there any way to make program restart every x minutes?

Comment: You could write a script that would kill and restart the task every 2-3 hours.

Comment: To follow up with what @gt6989b, I would write a Python script that simply loops and waits until 2-3 hours have passed, and then restarts the program.  You may find the Python [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and [sh](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh/0.107) modules useful.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7855501/1069083

Comment: If you have `systemd`, there's a nice configuration to restart on _failure_

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try doing in your `crontab` :

```
crontab -e
```

then

```
 11 */3 * * * /usr/bin/pkill -f appli_name; /path/to/appli_name & &>/dev/null
```

The `crontab` command mean :

- every 3 hours
- kill appli_name
- start appli_name in background

Comment: This is how I currently solve a similar issue. I restart a certain software every night at 0:00 via cron, since the software has a tendency to corrupt its state file after 4-5 days. I have installed the software as a service and then run `service <appname> restart > /dev/null 2>&1` at the wanted times.

Comment: Is there a way to give a job a name, in case my program is `python script.py` and I don't want to kill all python jobs?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to configure [Supervisor](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/supervisor) for your task. It can monitor the process, restart if it fails, also provides output redirection and other nice features. See the [example for program](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-example) to get started.

Comment: +1, this appears to be a more "clean" solution as opposed to `crontab` (although both solutions work just fine).  However, I find Supervisor is better at configuring what signals to send a process and when (i.e. when to send `SIGTERM`, and how long to wait before sending `SIGKILL`, etc...).